# How to send an email using C# Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

Using following [code example](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/documentation) I created a task:

```
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
      {
         // Create a new task definition and assign properties
         TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
         td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";

         // Add a trigger that, starting tomorrow, will fire every other week on Monday
         // and Saturday and repeat every 10 minutes for the following 11 hours
         WeeklyTrigger wt = new WeeklyTrigger();
         wt.StartBoundary = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
         wt.DaysOfWeek = DaysOfTheWeek.Monday | DaysOfTheWeek.Saturday;
         wt.WeeksInterval = 2;
         wt.Repetition.Duration = TimeSpan.FromHours(11);
         wt.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
         td.Triggers.Add(wt)

         // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
         td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("notepad.exe", "c:\\test.log", null));

         // Register the task in the root folder
         ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("Test", td);
      }
   }
```

But how can I programmatically add the following "Send an email" action shown in Windows Task Scheduler for the task I created.:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is an [EmailAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446868(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Using your suggestion I successfully created the email action. But I want to send an email if the task fails. So I [created a new post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018859/using-c-sharp-task-scheduler-managed-wrapper-how-to-trap-an-error-if-task-fails).

Answer (score 0):

The way to get there is give in this [blog](https://yoursandmyideas.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/task-scheduler-in-c-net/). You have to create a new action of the type

`_TASK_ACTION_TYPE.TASK_ACTION_SEND_EMAIL`

and bind that action during task registration