# Using C# Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper how to trap an error if task fails and send an email

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

Using following [code example](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/documentation) I created a task. The task runs and sends an email afterwards successfully. If the task fails how do I programmatically trap the failure and then sends an email:

```
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
      {
         // Create a new task definition and assign properties
         TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
         td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";

         // Add a trigger that, starting tomorrow, will fire every other week on Monday
         // and Saturday and repeat every 10 minutes for the following 11 hours
         WeeklyTrigger wt = new WeeklyTrigger();
         wt.StartBoundary = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
         wt.DaysOfWeek = DaysOfTheWeek.Monday | DaysOfTheWeek.Saturday;
         wt.WeeksInterval = 2;
         wt.Repetition.Duration = TimeSpan.FromHours(11);
         wt.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
         td.Triggers.Add(wt)

         // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
         td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("notepad.exe", "c:\\test.log", null));
         td.Actions.Add(new EmailAction("Test from win schedular", "myemaild@mydomain.com", "youremail@yourdomain.com", "Test body content", "smtp.test.com"));
         // Register the task in the root folder
         ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("Test", td);
      }
   }
```

Comment: I don't believe Windows Task Scheduler has a facility to email on failure so the wrapper API won't either. Take a look at http://superuser.com/questions/249103/make-windows-task-scheduler-alert-me-on-fail you could use that to make another scheduled task that looks for an event log entry indicating failure and emails you. That's the best I can think of.